# How are the SDKs under /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs installed?

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm using the default toolchain shipped with Xcode 13.1 on macOS 12 (Monterey).

```
$ sudo xcode-select -r
$ sudo xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

But I find there are two SDK directories under `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs`:

```
$ pwd
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs
$ ls -1
MacOSX10.14.sdk 
MacOSX10.15.sdk
```

I wonder how were they installed?

I upgraded my macOS (and hence Xcode) several times in the past. Were these SDKs installed during those upgrades? But since xcode was upgraded also, shouldn't it contain the up-to-date SDK under its `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains` directory? Why is it necessary to install a separate copy unnder `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs`?

Also, are SDK and toolchain the same thing? I thought they were, but I'm not sure now. I googled about this but found nothing helpful. I find an apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/AlternativeToolchains.html) explaining one can view available toolchains in Xcode by selecting `Preferences -> Components` in menu. I see nothing when using that approach, which seems to suggest MacOSX10.14.sdk and MacOSX10.15.sdk are not considered (valid?) toolchains on my system?

Or are SDKs under `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs` for macOS development only and the toolchains in Xcode contains more for iOS, iPad, etc? But if so, why isn't there MacOSX11.0.sdk and MacOSX12.0.sdk under `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs`?

I'm completely at lost. Thanks for any explanation.